# Transformerless Power Supply High Current

Tags: power-supply, power, current, transformerless

Is there any way for Transformerless Power Supply to output a High Current like 10A to 15A at 12V to 24V. I found highest of 500mA current output for Transformerless Capacitor Power Supply. I wanna use it for Lab requirements for an Electronics Engineer. Like running an Amplifier at 7Amp .

Comment: It's possible, just a terrible idea.

Comment: What voltage do you want? For what purpose do you need it? Technically, a wall socket is transformerless as well. :-P

Comment: A car battery does pretty well too and it's DC. Feed it from a decent solar panel for longer up-time.

Comment: Can you add to your question a photo/schematic/link to show what you found that is similar to what you want? Your description is too vague. Esp. what is the voltage in and out?

Comment: You are looking too closely at a solution, without letting us as a community evaluate the actual problem. You haven't given us any details at all about the application, and we need that if we're going to help you. Edit the question to include what this is for, *why you need it to be transformerless* and *what the voltage output needs to be*.

Comment: I don't have a schematic or photo cause that's what i need or mathematical base

Comment: When you say Lab requirements, you mean a bench power supply? Very bad idea to use a non isolated supply for connections which are going to be touched when on since there is a high likelihood of electric shock even though the output voltage difference is low, because of the voltage to earth. If you use it for an audio amplifier, any item you connect will share the "0V" point which makes that point on the other equipment live as well.

Comment: Large transformer-based supplies = big, very heavy, expensive, and moderately efficient. These provide galvanic isolation (isolation from Earth ground.) Many amplifiers employ "strange" usage of grounds, and would work fine with this type. Most switching-based supplies = tiny, lightweight, less expensive per watt output, and very efficient, but do NOT provide galvanic isolation.

Comment: @rdtsc that's why i want transformerless supply cause its cheap it got almost 0 heat and its light

Comment: as far as Amplifier goes!! it was just an example cause i need 7 Amp for a Amplifier I built but i got a transformer which only can handle 5 Amps

Comment: I also wanna use it for a battery charger in UPS (Urgent Power Supply)

Comment: You can get want you want with a switch mode power supply. Higher frequencies can make the transformer really small and very efficient while still providing galvanic isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microchip Application Note 954](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00954A.pdf) It is possible to create transformerless power supply circuits. The application note provides analysis information over some sample circuits and give formulas to calculate circuit parameters.

In the document, it is given 2 base models of circuits:

1. Capacitive circuit
2. Resistive circuit

Given the formulas and calculations, for example if it is needed to use like 200mA output current, the power dissipation of some important components rise to 100Watts. Which means higher the output current increases the power dissipation of components for the circuit. Thus to get this amount of power, the feasibility of the idea becomes negative.

In English: It is possible but NOT logical.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Really appreciate it. As an Engineer It just bugged me that why we still use such crude method as a transformer